# Chrome View or WebView Get Html Source Android

Tags: android, html, webview, chromeview

I use WebView to get html source code of a web-page by URL.
In my Moto G device (5.1.1) the code that i used with old device doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(getContext());
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "HtmlViewer");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");

           /* webview.evaluateJavascript("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');",null);*/


            /*view.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('MAGIC'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");*/
           // webview.evaluateJavascript("javascript:console.log('MAGIC'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);",null);
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(url);

 class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {
        //new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("HTML").setMessage(html)
          //      .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
        initStartAsyncTask(html);
    }

}
```

So I want to get HTML source too in Android

Answer (score 3):

I solved with this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                webview.evaluateJavascript(
                        "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
                        new ValueCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                                Log.d("HTML", html);
                                initStartAsyncTask(html);
                                // code here
                            }
                        });
            }else{
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                        "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
            }
```

Comment: For the script string, I used `"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;"` since I was only interested in the `<body>` contents (on KitKat+).

Comment: Could you tell me how to display the source code on toast ? what part of your initial post should i change with your above code ?